# Convert dd/mm/yyyy VARCHAR to yyyy-dd-mm DATETIME in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to convert a varchar(255) string (dp.Date) which has `dd/mm/yyyy` format (01/08/2017) to datetime in `yyyy-mm-dd format` (2017-08-01).

I've tried using `CONVERT(DATETIME, dp.Date, 120)`, but I end up with the following error message.

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: You need to use `CONVERT` to give it a format, not `CAST`: CONVERT(DATETIME,dp.Date,120)`

Comment: sorry, i meant to write CONVERT... as you can see I have used the syntax for CONVERT, too... edited the post... thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Then you have strings that are out of range for a date (like `05/15/2017`)

Comment: `DATETIME` in SQL Server has **no format** - it's a 8-byte **binary** value.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by using **CAST+SUBSTRING**.

cast(substring(dp.Date,7,4)+substring(dp.Date,4,2)+substring(dp.Date,1,2) AS datetime)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `PARSENAME` as below. Execution with sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Id INT, [Date] VARCHAR (255));

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Id, [Date]) VALUES
(1, '01/08/2017'), (2, '21/09/2017'), (3, '15/12/2017');

SELECT CAST(
            CONCAT(PARSENAME(DateValue, 1), '-', 
                   PARSENAME(DateValue, 2), '-', 
                   PARSENAME(DateValue, 3)) 
       AS DATETIME) AS [Date] 
FROM (
    SELECT REPLACE([Date], '/', '.') AS DateValue FROM @TestTable
) D
```